# how to get node value by EvaluateXpath processor?

Tags: xpath, apache-nifi

I have nifi processor  EvaluateXpath  and i  want to get  tags value   from  xml response ,  for it i use  expression like  this `//count/text()` but my  count  attribute is  still empty , what  should i change? 
my xml  reponse is  something like this, AND  I WANT TO GET THIS  72 AND  WRITE IT IN MY  COUNT ATTRIBUTE .

```
<SendMessage xmlns="http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
<EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
<Header>
<MessageDetails>
<Class></Class>
<Qualifier>response</Qualifier>
<Function>submit</Function>
<CorrelationID></CorrelationID>
<ResponseEndPoint/>
</MessageDetails>
<SenderDetails>
<IDAuthentication/>
<EmailAddress/>
</SenderDetails>
</Header>
<MessageDetails/>
<Body>
<Message xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
<getEventDataResponse xmlns="http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" xmlns:ns4="http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
<count>72</count>
</Message>
```

Comment: please provide the content of your flowfile and processor parameters. fyi:  `RouteOnContent` not getting any value. It just matching content to regexp.

Comment: you are  right  i use evaluatexpath  for  attribute now :\\count/text() but  it  doens't  work  also

Comment: is  there  any  way i  can  get  node  value  from  xml  response and  then  put it  into  attribute?

Comment: try to edit your question and provide full information in it. what you have and what do you want to get.

Comment: 1) are you sure all your `xmlns` (namespaces) are empty? this is very important for xpath. 2) the xml in your question is not valid. could you provide a valid xml?

Comment: I  know in original  version   it  has  namespaces,  i  have demonstrated it  in order  to make  clear  that  my expression  is  right

Comment: if you have namespace then your expression is wrong.

Comment: You mean this expresssion isn't  right : //count/text()

Comment: yes. the expression `//count/text()` isn't right if you have namespaces.  please modify your question and specify namespace values even fake ones. also fix the title of the question and labels of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have namespace in your message `xmlns="http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope"`

it means that the name of `count` node is `{http://www.talk.gov.uk/CM/envelope} count`

the nifi processor `EvaluateXPath 1.3.0` does not support namespaces however you can write your xpath like this to search for the element by local name:

```xml
//*[local-name()='count']/text()
```

[image]

Comment: daggett thank  you,  your answer  was  very  helpful